# How to know if the user dwelling inside the CLRegion after specific minutes in background?

Tags: ios, xcode, background, geofencing, clregion

I worked on geofencing iOS and everything is well .
Enter & Exit events are triggered .
How to detect if the user stay in the region after specific minutes? .
I can use `didDetermineState`       in the foreground with `NSTimer` 
to know if the `CLRegionStateInside`.
But in background how to check it please ?
In android there is `dwell Event`

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You can look at the visits API, but it will on,y notify you after the user leaves the location.  There is no way to launch your app in the background after "x" minutes on the device itself. You can use a server push

Comment: #Paulw11 Thanks for advice , CLVisit can't solve my problem